# batch line-by-line bitwise functions (bitwise logic operator equivalent of diff/comm?)

Tags: bash, shell, primes, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I'm researching the rhythmic elements of prime number sequences in binary. I have multiple sets of files containing vertical lists, and I want to apply bitwise logic operators between any two of them line-by-line.

i.e.

```
$cat binary-superprimes.txt
11
101
1011
10001
11111
101001
111011
1000011
1010011
1101101
$cat binary-perniciousprimes.txt 
11
101
111
1011
1101
10001
10011
11111
100101
101001
```

I'm looking for commands, a script, or an application (I'd prefer commands/a script but its not deal-breaking) that will let me and/or/xor/etc. these outputs in order line-by-line, in much the same style/similar to the output of `diff` or `comm`.

Using CentOS 7/Ubuntu 18.04/MacOS 10.15.

**edit**
Expected output (binary expansion of XORing each entry above in decimal):

```
0
0
1100
11010
10010
111000
101000
1011100
1110110
1000100
```

As for what I've tried, as I said I've played around with for loops, but I don't know how (or if its possible) two iterate two lists for comparison in this context (i.e. two "for i in"'s with a single "done" - using $i and $x as inputs for a basic "echo (($x^$i))"

I've also tried a program called "bitwise" but its output is too verbose and it cannot seem to read files, only values.

Comment: 1. Add an expected output for given samples and elaborate on the task. 2. Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I'd suggest using Python or C++/Java/etc. Bash is not optimal for this kind of tasks.

Comment: @NO_NAME, its not so hard to do it in shell :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `bash` version is >= 4.0 and supports `mapfile`,
would you try the following:

```
mapfile -t x < "binary-superprimes.txt"
mapfile -t y < "binary-perniciousprimes.txt"

for (( i=0; i<${#x[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "obase=2;" $(( 2#${x[i]} ^ 2#${y[i]} )) | bc
done
```

Output:

```
0
0
1100
11010
10010
111000
101000
1011100
1110110
1000100
```

In case your `bash` does not support `mapfile` command, please try the alternative:

```
while read -r line; do
    x+=($line)
done < "binary-superprimes.txt"

while read -r line; do
    y+=($line)
done < "binary-perniciousprimes.txt"

for (( i=0; i<${#x[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "obase=2;" $(( 2#${x[i]} ^ 2#${y[i]} )) | bc
done
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of reading both files into memory you could use `paste file1 file2 | while read x y; do ...; done`. This also works with older versions of bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bc` for this purpose. First you create file

`xor.bc`

```
define xor(x,y) {
 auto n,z,t,a,b,c,os,qx,qy;
 os=scale;scale=0
 n=0;x/=1;y/=1
 if(x<0){x=-1-x;n=!n}
 if(y<0){y=-1-y;n=!n}
 z=0;t=1;while(x||y){
  qx=x/4;qy=y/4;
  c=(a=x-4*qx)+(b=y-4*qy) 
  if(!c%2)c=a+4-b         
  z+=t*(c%4)
  t*=4;x=qx;y=qy
 }
 if(n)z=-1-z
 scale=os;return (z)
}
```

Then you create loop to get the numbers one by one. And you can exec `XOR` by this:

```
paste binary-superprimes.txt binary-perniciousprimes.txt |while read var1 var2;
do
    echo "ibase=2;obase=2;xor($var1;$var)|bc -l xor.bc
done
```